# Sort multiple lists lua

Tags: sorting, lua, draw

How can I sort 2 lists `y` location ( map tiles and people ) and draw them in order dependent of `y`. 2 lists I want to use:

```
map = {}
map.y = {60,10,40,80}
map.t = {0,0,1,1} -- type

people = {}
people.y = {0,100}
people.t = {0,1} -- type
```

I can currently sort and draw a single list of hero and boxes.
Sort / draw code:

```
box1 = love.graphics.newImage("box1.png")
box2 = love.graphics.newImage("box2.png")
box3 = love.graphics.newImage("box3.png")
hero = love.graphics.newImage("hero.png")

object = {
    x = {0, 50,100,200},
    y = {0,200, 50,100},
    g = {0,1,2,3}
}
function sortIndex(item)
    local i
    local id = {}       -- id list
    for i = 1, #item.x do   -- Fill id list (1 to length)
        id[i] = i
    end
--  print( unpack(id) ) -- Check before
    table.sort(id,sortY)-- Sort list
--  print( unpack(id) ) -- Check after
    item.sort = id      -- List added to object.sort
--  Sort id, using item values
    function sortY(a,b)
        return item.y[a] < item.y[b]
    end
end
function drawObject()
    local i,v, g,x,y
    for i = 1, #object.x do
        v = object.sort[i] -- Draw in order
        x = object.x[v]
        y = object.y[v]
        g = object.g[v]
        if      g == 0 then g = hero -- set to an image value
        elseif  g == 1 then g = box1
        elseif  g == 2 then g = box2
        elseif  g == 3 then g = box3
        end
        love.graphics.draw(g,x,y,0,7,7)
    end
end
```

Update sort:

```
sortIndex(object)
```

My function sorts an `id` list comparing a `y` location list. The `id` is used to draw objects in order dependent of their `y`. How can I sort 2 `id` lists together comparing 2 `y` location lists, then draw them in order?

Maybe when drawing, switch from map tiles to people dependent on `y`, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be related to your previous question a lot: [Returning A Sorted List's Index in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35309319/returning-a-sorted-lists-index-in-lua)

I assume if your height can be 1,2 and 3 (with 1 being on the top), you first want to render all tiles at Y1, then all people at Y1, then Y2 and Y3. To do that, you'll have to make a combined list and sort that:

```
map = {}
map.y = {60,10,40,80}
map.t = {0,0,1,1} -- type

people = {}
people.y = {0,100}
people.t = {0,1} -- type

local all = {}
local map_y = map.y
local offset = #map_y
local people_y = people.y
-- Fill the list with map tiles
for i=1,offset do
    all[i] = {1,i,map_y[i]} --{type,index,y}
end
-- Fill the list with people
for i=1,#people_y do
    all[i+offset] = {2,i,people_y[i]}
end
-- Do the sorting
-- It works a bit like your previous question:
-- 'all' contains "references":
--    They tell us is it's from map/people + the index
-- We sort the references using the third element in it:
--    The 'y' variable we put there during the first 2 loops
table.sort(all,function(a,b)
    return a[3] < b[3]
end)
-- Printing example
-- The references are sorted using the 'y' field of your objects
--    With v[1] we know if it's from map/people
--    The v[2] tells us the index in that ^ table
--    The v[3] is the 'y'-field. No real need to remove it
for k,v in pairs(all) do
    print(v[1] == 1 and "Map" or "Person",v[2],"with y being",v[3])
end
```

Output:

```
Person 1 with y being 0
Map 2    with y being 10
Map 3    with y being 40
Map 1    with y being 60
Map 4    with y being 80
Person 2 with y being 100
```

There are 2 things I want to add, that doesn't have anything to do with the question of my answer:

- Maybe it would be easier if you have a table for each element.
  Your people would be {0,0} and {100,1} which might be easier to manipulate.
- If you prefer your stuff always sorted, you might want to use this: [Sorted List](https://github.com/ROBLOX/Wiki-Lua-Libraries/blob/master/StandardLibraries/SortedList.lua). If you keep a sorted list of all your objects, you don't have to sort the list everytime you add/remove an element, or worse, each time you render. *(depending if people move)* This might help with performance if you're planning to have a lot of map/people objects. *(Sorted List could be useful for your current data system, but also the `{y=1,t=1}` one)*

Comment: Simple to use. Does what I wanted. Thankyou very much, and for providing comments. I was looking into combining lists for sorting, but I would not have been able to solve my problem (still learning important info about lua)

Answer (score 1):

```
function sortIndex(...)
  sorted = {}  -- global
  local arrays_order = {}
  for arr_index, array in ipairs{...} do
    arrays_order[array] = arr_index
    for index = 1, #array.y do
      table.insert(sorted, {array = array, index = index})
    end
  end
  table.sort(sorted,
    function (a,b)
      local arr1, arr2 = a.array, b.array
      local ind1, ind2 = a.index, b.index
      return arr1.y[ind1] < arr2.y[ind2] or
        arr1.y[ind1] == arr2.y[ind2] and arrays_order[arr1] < arrays_order[arr2]
    end)
end

function drawAll()
  for _, elem_info in ipairs(sorted) do
    local array = elem_info.array
    local index = elem_info.index
    local x = array.x[index]
    local y = array.y[index]
    if array == map then
      -- draw a map tile with love.graphics.draw()
    elseif array == people then
      -- draw a human with love.graphics.draw()
    end
  end
end

sortIndex(map, people)  -- to draw map tiles before people for the same y
```

Comment: Could you please explain this answer, rather than spoon feed code?

Comment: @warspyking - Please be more constructive in your critique: what exactly needs to be explained in my answer?  Which part of the answer is unclear for you?

Comment: @Egor I have no idea what you code does, perhaps explain what you're doing?

Comment: Simple to use. Does what I wanted. Thankyou very much for your answer.